# Javascript - Load HTML Url ID's into an Ajax url loader

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to load the html url variables such as id and sid into javascript.
For example in php it would be done via

```
<?php require_once("test.php?id=".$_GET['id']."&?sdi=".$_GEt['sid']) ?>
```

What would be the Javascrit / Ajax alternative?

Comment: Search on google "jquery load()"...

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/7385790) answer, I believe this is what you want.

Comment: @Jeoff Thats partially it, however that does not work when adding variables to the link as someone stated in the comments section